# ASP.NET Membership with PostgreSQL and dev.nauck.AspSQLProvider

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, npgsql

I am trying to use the PostgreSQL Membership provider created by Daniel Nauck
http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/aspsqlprovider
for an ASP.NET web application (C#) and followed the instructions for configuration given at

http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/1/wiki/Install?version=11

I have installed NpgSQL and the Membership provider with nuget:

```
Install-Package Npgsql
Install-Package Nauck.PostgreSQLProvider
```

When accessing the "Security" tab on the project-configuration-website I get the following error:

> exepath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe

I added the given SQL membership tables to my postgres database and specified the connection string, as well as the given configuration in the web.config file.

web.config:

```
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PostgreSQL" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=mydb;User Id=postgres;Password=mypassword;Encoding=UNICODE;Sslmode=Prefer;Pooling=true;" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <membership defaultProvider="PgMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="PgMembershipProvider" type="NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider.PgMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="PostgreSQL" requiresUniqueEmail="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="AquilaWeb" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="PgRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".AspNetRoles" cookiePath="/" cookieProtection="All" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" createPersistentCookie="false" cookieTimeout="30" maxCachedResults="25">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="PgRoleProvider" type="NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider.PgRoleProvider" connectionStringName="PostgreSQL" applicationName="AquilaWeb" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="PgProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="PgProfileProvider" type="NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider.PgProfileProvider" connectionStringName="PostgreSQL" applicationName="AquilaWeb" />
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" />
        <add name="LastName" />
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="PgSessionStateStoreProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="PgSessionStateStoreProvider" type="NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider.PgSessionStateStoreProvider" enableExpiredSessionAutoDeletion="true" expiredSessionAutoDeletionInterval="60000" enableSessionExpireCallback="false" connectionStringName="PostgreSQL" applicationName="AquilaWeb" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>

  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.12.0" newVersion="2.0.12.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try version [2.0.0](http://dev.nauck-it.de/versions/show/5) of the provider. It contains a bugfix the hosted environment detection in ASP.NET 4+

You can grap the latest build on [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider).

Documentation is available on [project wiki](http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/aspsqlprovider/wiki).

Comment: I am not sure if this did the trick, but I upgraded to version 2.0 and redid the installation process and now it works. So, thanks for pointing out the new version!